# Spring EntityGraphType.FETCH is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2 . I have faced an unusual issue that `EntityGraphType.FETCH` did not work whenever I fetch `User` entity.

It fetches all the `FetchType.EAGER` (`Company`, `UserFile`) entities regardless the `EntityGraph` type. I tried with `attributePaths` in repository, it has the same issue.

```java
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.noAssociation")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.profilePic", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("profilePic")})
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends TimeAudit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Company company;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserFile profilePic;

}
```

and

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "User.profilePic", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email="email")
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "User.profilePic", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email="email")
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

to

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "User.profilePic", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email="email")
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: It (EntityGraphType.LOAD) does not change any sql query.